# I cant delegate virtual path for error page

Tags: iis

```
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="ErrorPages" path="403.htm" responseMode="File" />
    </httpErrors>
```

Webconfig like this. I have 403.htm in my directory. But when ı deny an ıp and try to open . Just write you dont have permission to view this directory or pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
allowAbsolutePathsWhenDelegated="true"
```

I have fix my issue with configuration editor in IIS Manager .